# React Native how to navigate to route that isn't available in bottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigator

I have got simple bottomTabNavigator created with:

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Dashboard: {
            screen: Dashboard,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Panel',
                 tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintcolor}) => (
                    focused ?
                        <Icon
                            name='rowing'/> :
                        <Image
                            source={require('./img/menu/dashboard-g.png')}
                            style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
                        />
                )
            }
        },
        Employees: {
            screen: Employees,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Employees',
                tabBarIcon: () => (
                        <Image
                            source={require('./img/menu/dashboard-g.png')}
                            style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
                        />
                )
            }
        },
}
```

Every element of that list is displayed in bottom tab.

However on Dashboard I have got list of items with `onPress` property:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
   item: item
})}
```

Of course click on that item doesn't redirect me to Details screen because it isn't defined in navigator. On the other hand if I will define it in navigator then it will be displayed in bottom menu but that isn't what I would like to achieve.

Details is simple RN Component.

Please advice.

**UPDATE**
To clarify what I would like achieve I attach simple image with concept:
[image]

Screen 1: simple login page (no bottom menu)
Screen 2: main application screen (no bottom menu)
Screen 3: one of application screen with NavigatorTabMenu (bottom menu).

As you can see on screen 3 I would like to navigate to screen 5. Screen 5 never exists in menu so `this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen5")` won't work because screen 5 isn't in menu and it is not probably in some router so application don't know about that route.
The question is:
1. how to add some screens to routes that aren't in menu
2. it is possible to display menu presented on screen 3 on any other screens (like screen 5 or 6 that aren't navigable from that menu).

Hopefully that clarify my needs.

Comment: Where is "Details" defined?

Comment: Yes, please show the "Details" stack

Comment: @Auticcat
Details is simple RN Component.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your screen in [Stack Navigator](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation) which is not visible in bottom tab navigator with `bottom tab navigator`. 
Now you have to integrate both in the routes files. So that you will get your desired result.

> You can get a working example [here](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation)

Hope this helps, thanks :)